# use current URL param to manipulate navigation menu

Tags: php, url, parameters, navigationbar, isset

I am developing a little website with PHP only.

Is it possible to change the menu Links with the URL parameters the user used to visit the website?

The user visits the website with this url:

```
http://localhost/subpages/index.php?page=timeline&name=kay
```

So if the user name is mark for example, the menu should change to aboutmark instead of aboutkay.

```
    <html>
      ..
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" href="profilepages/index.php?page="<? 'about'.$name ?> Über mich</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" href="profilepages/index.php?page="<? 'timeline'.$name ?> Timeline</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" href="profilepages/index.php?page="<? 'friends'.$name ?> Friends</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" href="profilepages/index.php?page="<? 'photos'.$name ?> Fotos</a></li>
      ..
    </html>
```

My code to change the main content of the website looks like this:

```
<?
    if ((isset($_GET['page'])) && (isset($_GET['name'])))
               {
                 $page = $_GET['page'];
                 $name = $_GET['name'];
               }
                else
                    {
                      $page = 'test';
                      $name = 'name';
                    }

     if ((preg_match('/^[a-z0-9\-]+$/', $page)) && (preg_match('/^[a-z0-9\-]+$/', $name)))
               {
                    $inserted = include('profilepages/'.$page.$name.'.php');

                    if (!$inserted)
                    echo('Requested page was not found.');
                }
                 else
                    echo('Invalid parameter.');
                ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shoutout to a friend of mine.

Just get the var of the URL ...name=var

via

```
<?php $name = $_GET['name'];?>
```

and use `<?php echo $name ?>`

like this:

```
<li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" href="profilepages/index.php?page="<?php echo $name ?> Über mich</a></li>
```